# What exactly does @Autowired mean in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I am very new to Java and I am going through a code-base written in Java.

There is a class which has a member variable declared like this:

```
private TagMapper tagMapper;
```

Just on top of this, **@Autowired** is written.
In all of the methods of that class, **tagMapper**, was directly used, I didn't find any TagMapper object being instantiated for this member variable.

Does **@Autowired** create an object, without us having to specifically instantiate one?

I went through couple of other answers on **@Autowired**, they were a bit complicated; for my present state; to understand.

Can I get a simple explanation?

Comment: It is an annotation that is interpreted by Spring. (Note that it not considered best practice to use it on fields; use constructors instead.)

Comment: You can refer spring docs for Autowiring - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-autowire

Comment: Yes, spring is complex, maybe too complex for someone who is very new to java itself. But there is no easy way around it, you simply need to understand spring and dependency injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DependencyInjection` popularly known as `DI` conceptualizes the process of delegating the responsibility to create and provide dependencies. Makes the code organized and modular.

Each component ( Class / Module ) is responsible for declaring its dependencies and Container ( Environment where this class is initialized ) provides the required dependencies.

`@Autowired` is an annotation used by spring to denote that required dependency will be fulfilled by Spring. Corresponding java spec is `@Inject`

Ref Spring Docs for details:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: "...required dependency will be fulfilled by Spring.", does that mean an object will be created by Spring and given to the class? @Akash Yadav

Comment: Yes, provided you configure the spring bean, Also make sure you create the object of current class via Spring